# Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in 'package.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

Tags: reactjs, heroku, plugins, eslint, prettier

I installed `eslint` and `Prettier` in my project and I'm trying to deploy it on heroku
but I still getting error ( failure deploy ).

```
 Failed to compile.
       
       Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in 'package.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'
       Require stack:
       - /tmp/build_e0cdc90b/client/node_modules/react-scripts/config/__placeholder__.js
       Referenced from: /tmp/build_e0cdc90b/client/package.json
```

#### How can I solve this problem ?

`package.json file`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "antd": "^4.16.13",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended",
      "prettier"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```